# Too much context in search results

Tags: bug, search

I just performed a search on SO and clicking on the last page of the result list I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=862&tab=relevance&q=body%3a%22same%20problem%22).

Some results are listed with too much details IMO. I suppose that since my query was `body:"same problem"` the engine is trying to highlight the `same problem` string, but it seems that it gives too much context around the occurrences of that string.

Is this a bug or is it by design?

Comment: @TimStone Yep it seems a duplicate, yet the other question has a title that doesn't make it easy to find using the search. Moreover it has no answers too.

Comment: Your improved title will help people find the original bug report. I'm guessing it won't receive an answer until an SE dev decides whether it will be fixed.

Comment: @Duncan Mmm so it is definitely a bug, thanks. I guess we must live with it, since it seems it has had little attention by the devs in 8 months (could it be such a difficult bug to squash?)

Comment: [Because there are thousands of bugs!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bug]+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano)

Comment: @Duncan Ouch! Never noticed before! They should be quite busy, indeed!

Comment: @Duncan, I think it's [2/3 less](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D+-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D) than your original search...

Comment: @brasofilo [Even fewer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bug]+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+-[status-completed]+-[status-bydesign]+-[status-declined]) perhaps... Still - plenty!